# Excel VBA forces me to use Select when adding data validation in cells

Tags: excel, vba, validation

VBA is forcing me to use *Select* in order to be able to add data validation to a cell.

The way I wanted to do it is:

R is a Range received as a Parameter in the Sub since it is dynamically taken.

```
  With Cells(R.Row, 5).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateDate, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlLessEqual, Formula1:="=TODAY()"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = False
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = "Error"
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = "Fecha incorrecta"
    .ShowInput = False
    .ShowError = True
 End With
```

It stops in the .Add function giving a 1004 error.

The way it forces me to do it is:

```
Cells(R.row, 5).Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateDate, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlLessEqual, Formula1:="=TODAY()"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = False
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = "Error"
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = "Fecha incorrecta"
    .ShowInput = False
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Comment: Can't reproduce this, works fine for me w/o `Select`.

Comment: @BigBen Could it be the Office version? Maybe in old versions it doesn't work. I.E: Office 2003.

Comment: You're using 2003 then?

Comment: @BigBen Well, XP. Cause we use XP at job and want to stay with a familiar functionality and interface.